# Firebase Token generator fails in APN

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

What's the whitelist for Firebase push messaging and token generator? Because over an open network things works but over APN it's not working. 
I receive the below error on my logcat

E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed without exception message. Will retry token retrieval

Answer (score 2):

Are you on emulator ?
if Yes,

1, Check if you have internet connection in your emulator.

2, Check if a new version of the Google Play library has been released and your test device/emulator need update his currently installed version.

Comment: No, it's on a device.